# Django as Python extension?

Tags: python, django

I come from **php** community and just started learning **Python**. I have to create server-side scripts that manipulate databases, files, and send emails.

Some of it I found hard to do in python, comparing to php, like sending emails and querying databases.

Where in **php** you have functions like **mysql_query()**, or **email()**, in python you have to write whole bunch of code. Recently I found Django, and my question is: is it a good framework for network-oriented scripts, instead of using it as a web-framework?

Comment: As someone who started out in PHP, stick with Python - I don't want to hurt any love you have for PHP - But you are going from a Ford Fiesta to a Bentley - you won't have to look  back.

Answer (score 15):

### Disclaimer

**This answer does not say which language is better**, its sole purpose is to show Python code for things you said you needed from Django and tries to prove that in Python, as contrary to some other languages, you do not need frameworks to perform needed actions.

### Python's "batteries included" vs. PHP

In **PHP you often need a framework** or separate script / library to perform some more advanced tasks.

In **Python a lot of tools come bundled**, thus the term "batteries included", referring to multiple standard modules you can use without need to download them etc.

Thus your approach from PHP may not work - Python itself is very powerful and does not need frameworks for most features.

### Querying the database in Python vs. PHP

Actually in Python it is a lot easier to do such things as querying the database. For example querying the database looks like that in Python:

```
import MySQLdb as db

conn = db.connect(host='localhost', user='user', passwd='password', db='database')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `some_table`')
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

where the first line (`import` statement) can involve other databases (such as `sqlite3`), as **Python approach is to have the same interface for different RDBMSs**. This means a lot of flexibility.

In PHP you may write the same thing similar to this:

```
<?php 

$db = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password') or die("Database error"); 
mysql_select_db('database', $db); 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `some_table`'; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    // do what you need with $row
}
```

which **uses 4 MySQL-specific PHP functions**. This code will not work for different RDBMs without replacing these functions. Of course, the better approach would be to use eg. PDO, but you said you are using `mysql_query()` function - my example just follows that.

### Sending emails in Python

Here is an example from [documentation page](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html) using SMTP:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText('Hello, world!')
msg['Subject'] = 'This is an email title'
msg['From'] = 'me@example.org'
msg['To'] = 'you@example.com'

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

In PHP sending email may be very easy (and shorter, as in case of [`mail()` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)), but considering some often used solutions for sending emails through SMTP in PHP, Python's approach may be considered a lot simplier.

### Conclusion

**Python is fun! :)** If you need to query the database, it is a pleasure to do it in Python. If you want to send emails, Python has built-in module for it too. **You do not need to use big, complex frameworks to accomplish these tasks.**

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer! I have a problem running this email script though, it says: socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Do you know what the problem might be? It seems like python didn't like s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost') part for some reason.

Comment: @NoobDev4iPhone: Error message says it all, the connection has been refused. Check the IP and port (if they are correct), check the firewall on both machines, client and server (if it blocks the connection, make it pass through), and if it fails, maybe replace `localhost` with actual IP address, as it may not be a localhost.

Comment: I've retracted the downvote and deleted my comments, as after your update they were redundant. And Python is indeed fun!

Comment: @YannisRizos: Thanks! Yes, it is. PHP also gains a lot with newer versions (5.3 was major improvement and I regret to say I saw too much hosting providers with default PHP version below that, but that is off-topic). I am going to remove my comments as they are pointless now. Good luck!

Comment: I guess you also need to show that you will need to be iterating over `result` in the Querying The Database in Python example to be fair.

Comment: @loudandclear: Or I should replace `cursor.fetchall()` with solution using `cursor.fetchone()`, or change PHP example to one using PDO and [PDOStatement->fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), but let's agree I am not trying to prove (PHP|Python) is better than (Python|PHP) and it does not really matter in that level of detail. I am not trying to write two apps for OP (one in PHP and one in Python for comparison).

Comment: Python is less of an eyesore than PHP, that's for sure. All of those "$"... ugh.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are many Python libraries you can use instead of using a giant web framework.

Have a look at: http://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces to help you decide on a database interface; And a quick google query revealed: http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html as a possible solution to sending email.

Point being, a framework like Django is aimed at solving a specific problem, that being - easily creating a feature-rich website using Python. Not sending emails. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just found out about DatabaseInterfaces, which should work for me. But is there a way to send email without SMTP, with custom from-address, like you do in php? I want to send emails from localhost and can't find the solution to do so.

Comment: Looks like you're not the first to ask this question, a quick google search would have solved your problems. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485620/send-email-in-python-like-php

Answer (score 2):

If you are still using `mysql_*` functions, your PHP skills are *extremely* outdated.

`mysql_*` are essentially deprecated since `mysqli_*` functions came to be, and even `mysqli_*` has long been surpassed by [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php). Also there's no `email()` function, but [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). This may just be a typo in the question, if it is please ignore me.

Now as for the core of your question: (Almost) Everything that's available "out of the box" in PHP is also available in Python. You have to dig a little deeper into Python, before assuming a feature doesn't exist, your examples are pretty basic and a [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+mysql) [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20email) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [Python's online documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/) would have sufficed.

Although I'm *primarily* a PHP developer, I'm not advocating PHP over Python. Both are beautiful languages (in their own ways), with vibrant communities and healthy and stable ecosystems. And both are great for web development. You should choose the one that helps you be more productive, the one you find more fun to work with.

As for [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29): It's a framework for web applications, based on the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It's a Python equivalent to PHP frameworks like [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) and [others](http://www.google.gr/search?gcx=w&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20mvc%20framework).

You should use it when building Python applications that would require you to use an MVC framework if you were building them in PHP. So if your network-oriented PHP scripts don't use an MVC framework, Django probably won't be good fit either.